# How to create a new column from the select of the distinct values of two columns with Power Query Editor in Power Bi

Tags: powerbi

I need to insert in a new column the distinct values of two columns using the Power Query Editor Power Bi.
Any ideas [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SnMqc.png)guys?

Comment: An example of what your table might look like would help.

Comment: Show us your table and your data. What’s your 2 column??

Comment: Hi guys, here an example, I want to create the column Col3 from Col1 and Col1 https://i.stack.imgur.com/SnMqc.png

Answer (score 0):

Here you go:

```
let
    Source = SomeTable
    firstCol = Source[FirstColumn],
    secondCol = Source[SecondColumn],
    thirdCol = List.Sort(List.RemoveNulls(List.Distinct(List.Combine( {firstCol, secondCol})))),
    #"TableResult" = Table.FromColumns({firstCol, secondCol, thirdCol}, {"First","Second","Combined"})

in
    #"TableResult"
```

This basically converts your first and second columns into lists, and combines them into one new list.  Next, it transforms the new list a bit to match your requirements -- first by getting just the distinct values, then dropping any null values, and lastly sorting it in ascending order.

Once that's done, we can take advantage of Table.FromColumns and create a table from our three lists.

That should get you where you're going.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks Ryan.

My requirement was to create a **distinct list of IP addresses** from one of the columns in a Table.

Here's the code that worked for me.

```
= let
    Source = #"TABLENAME",
    firstCol  = #"TABLENAME"[Client Ip],
    IP = List.Distinct(firstCol),
    #"DistinctIP" = Table.FromColumns({IP}, {"IP"})
in
    #"DistinctIP"
```